# Отобразить текст в центре и в правой части экрана

Tags: css

Нужно чтобы текст был в центре и справа, но центр блока смещается относительно float: right (второй блок). Нужно чтобы осталась прежднаяя середина в блоке (как в первом блоке)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вставьте код , а не скриншот кода.

Comment: .test
{
 height: 48px;
 max-width: 400px;
 background-color: red;
 text-align: center;
}

.center
{
}

.right
{
 float: right;
} он коприруется криво

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
.align {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
}

.align > div {
  width: 100%;
}

.align .center {
  text-align: center;
}

.align .right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="align">
  <div class="center">Center text</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="align">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="center">Center text</div>
  <div class="right">Right text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ничего не поменялось

Comment: @l3m0n4ikk, не о том думал.. Обновил ответ